# How do I identify the magnitude of the list of values ​and use different equations for different regions?

Tags: python

Code:

```
rho_list = np.arange(10000, dtype = 'float64') * 0.0002 * rhoe

F_rho_list = []

for rhoi in rho_list:

    if 0.0 <= rhoi < rhol:
        F_rho_list += [Fm0 + Fm1*(rhoi/rhol -1) + Fm2*np.power(rhoi/rhol -1, 2) + Fm3*np.power(rhoi/rhol -1, 3)]

    elif rhol <= rhoi < rhon:
        F_rho_list += [Fn0 + Fn1*(rhoi/rhon -1) + Fn2*np.power(rhoi/rhon -1, 2) + Fn3*np.power(rhoi/rhon -1, 3)]

    elif rhon <= rhoi <rho0:
        F_rho_list += [F0 + F1*(rhoi/rhoe -1) + F2*np.power(rhoi/rhoe -1, 2) + F3*np.power(rhoi/rhoe -1, 3)]

    elif rhoi >= rho0:
        F_rho_list += [Fe*(1- etha*np.log(rhoi/rhoe))*np.power(rhoi/rhoe, etha)]
```

rho_list is a list from 0 to 2*rhoe.

For different values or different regions, I want to use different equations to calculate F_rho value and put it into F_rho_list.

I know that I can use

```
F_rho_list[(rho_list>=0) & (rho_list<rhol)]
```

to pick numbers. However, I don't know how to insert those numbers into different equations.

Can anyone solve such problems more easily? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a example that looks more structural. But I think the way you did it is already good enough to solve the problem.

```py
def func1(x, left, right):
    return x + 2

def func2(x, left, right):
    return 2 * x

def func3(x, left, right):
    return x - 3

funcs = [func1, func2, func3]
segments = [0, 1, 5, 10]

rho_list = np.linspace(0, 10, 10000)
F_rho_list = np.zeros_like(rho_list)
for left, right, func in zip(segments[:-1], segments[1:], funcs):
    rng = (rho_list >= left) & (rho_list < right)
    F_rho_list[rng] = func(rho_list[rng], left, right)
```